# Create Table Postgres in new schema does not complete

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

When trying to run a simple create statement in a new schema within postgres (`healthcare`), the query never finishes. My question is why?

```
CREATE TABLE healthcare.admission_source(
    admission_source_id INTEGER, 
    admission_source INTEGER,
    description varchar(255)
);
```

Verified the schema exists with ownership & rights:

[image]

I have ran this same query before, and it runs endlessly. I canceled it at several hours last time, but wanted to show it takes a long time to run a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

[image]

---

For comparison, the query runs for 42 msec on the `public` schema of this database. The table is created correctly and the query finishes quickly, so leaves me thinking that the `healthcare` schema is the issue. Would love all thoughts and assistance
[image]

Comment: which version of postgres?

Comment: @nbk  PostgreSQL 13.8, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Comment: Which client application are you using? Does it have `autocommit=off`? Could be the `CREATE` has never been committed.

Comment: ran `\echo :AUTOCOMMIT;` and it returned `on;`

Comment: there is alreaedy 13.14 out there try to update your system

Comment: 1) Make your life easier and use the Postgres command line client psql to do this. 2) Do a select on [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). I'm guessing there is a query on `healthcare.admission_source` that is holding a lock and preventing the `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably blocking on a lock. If you have log_lock_waits turned on, you can look in the log file to see what is going on.

This could happen for example of another session tried to create a table of the same name inside a transaction and didn't commit the transaction.

Comment: This was exactly the issue - had a lock state on the queries and some that were idle. I was trying to run a create table from jupytr notebook while also in PG Admin. 

SOLUTION: I ran ```select *
from pg_stat_activity
where cardinality(pg_blocking_pids(pid)) > 0;``` which showed me the blocked queries. Then ran `select pg_cancel_backend(<PID>);` &
`select pg_terminate_backend(<PID>);` to terminate the locks. Have then successfully created the tables in the new schema. Thanks @jjanes and @Adrian Klaver

Comment: Glad it was solved. What it shows is the importance of holding connections open for only the period necessary to do the work and then closing them.